# How to tell Vuetify component to fill the remaining height on screen?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Given a page with some content above and below a table. I want that table to fill the remaining height of the page, other elements should not be affected. So the content below that table should always be visible at the bottom of the page.

This is my [reproduction sample code](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <div>
        <v-alert type="success" title="Some content above"></v-alert>
        <div class="my-2">some more content</div>
        <v-table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Col 1</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="i in 100">
              <td>{{ i }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </v-table>
        <v-pagination :model-value="1" :length="10" class="my-2"></v-pagination>
      </div>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

I tried to add [flex](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/) with `flex-direction: column` to the `div` element but I think that's not correct, I don't want the elements to grow/shrink, I have to limit the page height first.

So I tried to use a [grid](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/) like [this](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container class="fill-height">
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-alert type="success" title="Some content above"></v-alert>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <div class="my-2">some more content</div>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Col 1</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="i in 100">
                  <td>{{ i }}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </v-table>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-pagination :model-value="1" :length="10" class="my-2"></v-pagination>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

but as you can see in the playground things are getting even worse. This is what I'm looking for

[image]

I think that I could solve this with CSS and vanilla JavaScript but I'm looking for a "Vuetify" solution.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Vuetify solution as far as I know, but the solution doesn't require that much CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.v-alert {
  overflow: visible;
}
.v-table {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[Vuetify Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

To hide the disabled full page scrollbar you can add

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It just doesn't work in the playground because of the iframe, but should work locally.